# Chain methods on String without core extensions

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a way (or perhaps a best practice) to chain various methods on a string object without actually opening up the `String` class. This is because the transformations I want to apply to the String object are fairly project specific, and I don't see a reason to pollute the global space with it.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe a wrapper of some sort? I experimented with `gsub!` on an instance variable but `gsub!`, unless the `gsub`, throws `nil` on failure to match, so it halts the chaining I want to achieve.

Basically, I need to be able to do:

```
"my_string".transformation1.transformation2.transformation3
```

and get to keep all those transformations namespaced to my application. Any ideas?

Comment: Can always add to an instance.

Comment: @DaveNewton I could, but that would be expensive since all these transformations are the same.

Comment: ... Then add it to string, or use a "concern" implementation, likely also a bit expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a method to an instance, but you're going to need to jump through a hoop to chain the methods:

```
str = 'now is the time'

def str.foo(target, replacement)
  self.gsub(target, replacement)
end

def str.bar
  self.reverse
end

str.singleton_methods # => [:foo, :bar]
str.foo('ow', 'ever') # => "never is the time"
str.bar # => "emit eht si won"
```

This won't work:

```
str.foo('ow', 'ever').bar

# ~> NoMethodError
# ~> undefined method `bar' for "never is the time":String
```

You can use "bang" type methods, that mutate the original object:

```
str = 'now is the time'

def str.foo(target, replacement)
  self.gsub!(target, replacement)
  self
end

def str.bar
  self.reverse!
  self
end

str.singleton_methods # => [:foo, :bar]

str.foo('ow', 'ever').bar # => "emit eht si reven"
```

Be careful though. This won't work on every type of object, only ones that allow mutating.

And, the fact that the added methods are only available to that particular variable is really limiting; It's messier reusing that same functionality. You can `clone` the variable and assign that clone to a new variable, but replacing the value with something different becomes messy:

```
str2 = str.clone
str.object_id # => 70259449706680
str2.object_id # => 70259449706520
str.singleton_methods # => [:foo]
str2.singleton_methods # => [:foo]

str2 = 'all good men'
str2.foo('ll', '') # => 

# ~> NoMethodError
# ~> undefined method `foo' for "all good men":String
```

Personally, I'd do it through a subclass:

```
class MyString < String
def foo(s, t)
  self.gsub(s, t)
end
end

str = MyString.new('now is the time')
str.foo('ow', 'ever') # => "never is the time"

str2 = 'all good men'
str2.foo('ll', '') # => 

# ~> NoMethodError
# ~> undefined method `foo' for "all good men":String
```

---

If you're on Ruby v2+, look at @mdesantis's answer using refinements. They were introduced to solve this sort of problem. If you're < v2.0, I'd go the sub-class route or accept having to modify String.

Comment: I went with subclassing it. Much cleaner and very scoped to my application.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Ruby >= 2.0 you can use [refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html):

```
module MyRefinements
  refine String do
    def transformation1
      # ...
      self
    end
    def transformation2
      # ...
      self
    end
    def transformation3
      # ...
      self
    end
  end
end

# Either in global scope (active until the end-of-file)
# or in lexical scope (active until the lexical scope end)
# More on this in the refinements docs scope section

# global scope
using MyRefinements
"test".transformation1.transformation2.transformation3 #=> "test"

# lexical scope
begin
  using MyRefinements
  "test".transformation1.transformation2.transformation3 #=> "test"
end
```

Comment: +1. I forgot about refinements. Dang these new-fangled things. :-)

Comment: @theTinMan I must admit I never used them in production code yet :D just for experiments; but I found them quite smart, I will use them at the next opportunity

Comment: Thank you @mdesantis. I liked them as well but ended up going with subclassing.

Comment: I've been playing with refinements in some code today, that'll never need Ruby < v2.0. I think they're a good idea, especially for people writing gems or sharing code, as refinements help protect the sanctity of the various built-in classes. For a non-shared script, where the chance of colliding with methods is low, then extending/overriding or sub-classing is still pretty safe.

Comment: Subclassing is a good solution for shared libraries too, but it doesn't allow to extend already existing classes, so in this is quite different from refinements; the use case of refinements IMHO is when you really want to extend/override builtin classes (String, Array, ...), usually for utility methods used in medium-large projects; while the use case of subclassing is when you want to specify a type creating a new class. F.e., `DNA` could be a subclass of `String` with f.e. a characters inclusion validation (`ATCG`) etc., and implementing it as refinement would be a mistake

Comment: Exactly @mdesantis. My project is too specific to actually throw everything in the String class. A new type is the best of both worlds.